# Open Chrome tab in background using command line

Tags: command-line, google-chrome

I would like to run a New Instance of Chrome from command line in Windows but would like it to open in background. Is this possible?
I know about   start chrome --incognito --url %%a  which starts a new incognito window but the problem with this is that I am loading multiple urls in new tabs and each time one is loaded focus switches to that new tab (Essentially you can not do anything until all the url-s are opened).

Comment: Was you able to find answer of your question?

Answer (score 1):

try to do this

```
--user-data-dir=/some/directory
```

to start a new session.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I found that switch in one of the StackOverflow questions but my main problem is not with the user session but with fact that new tabs started are focused instead of opening in background.